In Ubuntu 22.04.4 the screen blanking does not seem to keep screen blank - I find the screen on the next day - how do I fix this?
I've set the screen blanking to the lowest setting - 1 minute.  Then I wait one minute and the screens go blank.  I return to the screens the next day and the screens are not blank, they are on and appear to have been on for a long time.  One pattern I see is that there is a notification showing at the top of the screen (Software updates available, Backup finished, Update available for Firefox, etc), so this seems to be the reason the screen wakes up and stays awake.
So how do I get the screen to stay blank, or at least time out again to blank, even when notifications occur?

Thanks!  I'll give that a try and report back.  This started after I upgraded to 22 from 20, so maybe that setting got lost in the upgrade.
